# Office 365 Web panel opens without clicking it

Tags: microsoft-office

When I am logged into Microsoft O365 on the main/primary dashboard, the left navigation pane that shows all your applications keeps opening and closing on its own. What is causing this and how can I fix it?

This happens in Office 365 on the Chrome browser. The App Launcher on the main screen (the dashboard) opens and closes while I am working in the browser. I don't click the 9 box shortcut in the upper left corner but if I move my mouse around, the app launcher panel opens and closes randomly. --- I tried using FireFox and the same issue occurs. –

Comment: Have you tried changing the mouse to test?

Comment: @Emily - Hello!  We have tried changing the mouse and also tested on another laptop  The issue seems to follow the user account.